# Less sign (<) is not displayed on kendo binding to html

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a td element:

```
<td data-bind="html: name"></td>
```

I have data in JavaScript as

```
var name = '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.Name))';
```

The Model name is `<tag` or `< tag`.

In javascript it looks like: `\u003ctag` and `\u003c tag`.

In the first case I don't see the `<tag` and everything after it.

In the second case I do see the `< tag`.

Why doesn't the first case work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) doesn't know what to do with the parameter you're giving it.
In the second case, the input is simply treated as text, which is why it displays, but in the first case, it tries to interpret as HTML (that's what innerHTML and kendo's html binding are for, after all).

If you're trying to display `<tag`, then you should simply use text binding:

```
<td data-bind="text: name"></td>
```

If Model.Name actually contains HTML which is supposed to be rendered, it should be well-formatted and have closing tags.

Examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/qkzEt/